# VSFTPD - Service can't start with listen=YES

Tags: server, sftp, vsftpd

I have troubles with vsftpd service. When I keep default configuration file (`vsftpd.conf`) `systemctl status vsftpd` shows output `Active: active (running)`,but when I set only `listen=YES` the output becomes `Active: failed`. Why?

Comment: Does the configuration include `listen_ipv6=YES` as well?

Comment: @steeldriver yes, it does

Comment: You will need to set that to NO if you want to set `listen` to YES - see below

Answer (score 0):

If you enable `listen`, then you must disable `listen_ipv6`. From `man vsftpd.conf`:

> ```
>    listen_ipv6
>           Like  the listen parameter, except vsftpd will listen on an IPv6
>           socket instead of an IPv4 one. Note that a socket  listening  on
>           the  IPv6 "any" address (::) will accept both IPv6 and IPv4 con‐
>           nections by default. This parameter and the listen parameter are
>           mutually exclusive.
> ```